# Why I am able to write method definition in an Interface?

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I always learnt that, we cannot write method definition inside an Interface, but when I tried to do so, I was able to. Even the code was build successfully and there were no compile time errors.
Is it a new feature or something else?

Environment details
Language - C#,
Software - Visual Studio 2019,
.Net Framework - 5.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpsU7.jpg)

Comment: It was intruduced in c#8 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods

Comment: _These preceding member declarations typically do not contain a body. Beginning with C# 8.0, an interface member may declare a body._

Comment: So, you suspected it might be a new language feature. Did it occur to you to look at the "what's new" documentation between a version you're familiar with and the current version? Why not?

Answer (score 2):

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/default-interface-methods-versions):

> Beginning with C# 8.0 on .NET Core 3.0, you can define an implementation when you declare a member of an interface. The most common scenario is to safely add members to an interface already released and used by innumerable clients.

Default interface methods provide a way to extend interfaces with new members without breaking previous implementers.